# Who’s the villain in the Powerless trailer?

Tags: dc, powerless-tv

NBC's upcoming [Powerless Tv Show](http://www.nbc.com/powerless?CID=Search%7CPowerless&nbc=1) (based on DC Characters) shows two powered individuals fighting in the city. One is Crimson Fox -[citation](https://moviepilot.com/p/easter-egg/3923782), but who is the villain (possibly Jack O'Lantern)?

[image]

[image]

Although, [Jack O'Lantern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jack_O'Lantern_(DC_Comics)) is purple in the comics.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is [Jack O'Lantern](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt5083928/).  Casting aside, he calls himself by name repeatedly in the pilot.  And in the episode, he was more purple.  It is hard to tell in the promo due to all the smoke around him.